# std::ostreambuf_iterator and std::cout cannot be used together

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a code to understand usage of std::ostreambuf_iterator:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello Boy";
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> s2(std::cout);
    std::cout << " s2 = " << *s2 << std::endl;
}
```

But the compilation fails stating "no operator << matches operands" - can we not use << on ostreambuf_iterator? Then how can we print the values held by the iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read from an output stream, so an output stream iterator cannot return anything meaningful from `operator*`.

> Then how can we print the values held by the iterator?

The iterator doesn't hold any data. It writes to the stream that was provided to it when `operator=` is called.